# To trigger event opening vuejs page

Tags: events, vuejs2

In vuejs 2.5 .7/ vuetify1.0.8 application I  have several links to the same page(cmsItemPage), but with different alias parameter
and depending on this alias the content of the page must be different:

```
  <div class="headline text-xs-center">
    <router-link :to="{name: 'cmsItemPage', params: {alias: 'concerts_soon'} }">
       <span v-html="concerts_soonCmsItem.title"></span>
    </router-link>
 </div>
 ...
 <div class="headline text-xs-center">
    <router-link :to="{name: 'cmsItemPage', params: {alias: 'tours_soon'} }">
       <span v-html="tours_soonCmsItem.title"></span>
    </router-link>
 </div>
```

The question is that opening cmsItemPage page I need to take some event depending on alias parameter.
But not created or mounted events are not triggered at this case!

If there is a way to trigger some event in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Vue Router? Because you could do something [like this](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can watch route or use Route Guards to do that.
for example:

```
watch: {
  '$route': function(){
    console.log(this.$route.params.alias)
  }
}
```

or

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  console.log(to.params.alias)
  next()
}
```